# Can I delete the MBR from GRUB?

Tags: grub, mbr

Can I delete the Master Boot Record from GRUB? If so, how?

Comment: No as the MBR is not stored in Grub ;)

Comment: Could you describe what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What does it even mean to delete the MBR?  You can overwrite it, but you can't delete it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you would want to delete the Master Boot Record (MBR).  The boot part is the first 446 bytes on the disk.  The next 66 bytes store the partition information (64 bytes) and MBR signature (2 bytes), for a total of 512 bytes.  If you want to just wipe the boot code, you can run `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=446 count=1` where `sdX` is the name of your disk (typically sda).  But, before you do that, I would run `fdisk -l` and write down all the information, in case an accident clobbers your partition information.

Many places will just tell you the MBR is 512 bytes, but if you wipe all 512 bytes, you'll delete your MBR partition information.  If you're still using the old MBR partitioning scheme, this can usually be recovered with utilities that search the hard drive to find all the partitions.  However, it can be slow to scan every sector until all your partitions are found, and it's probably not something you want to do.  If you wrote the information down, you can just re-enter it and use the partition like it was never deleted, assuming it wasn't hit too.

GPT partition tables just store a single dummy partition in the MBR that marks the entire disk as a partition of type 0xEE (GPT), and store the actual partition information elsewhere.  I suppose it's up to the software whether deleting the dummy partition is okay.

Since you can control what devices are booting from the BIOS, I don't see much use for deleting the Master Boot Record.  Skipping the partitioning and file system to write directly to the disk always carries a danger (especially for typos).  For example, if you accidentally hit an extra number for the block size, you'll wipe part of your first partition, or if you forget count=1 and don't put any byte limit at all, then you'll wipe your entire disk (well...however much it can write before you notice and kill the process).

Answer (score 1):

You want to delete the MBR from the disk, not from grub. The MBR is just the first few bytes on the disk. This should do what you want.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

The MBR also contains the partition table, so formatting it will also delete all your partitions. As a result, your going to either A: Create a backup of your current partition table or B: Reinstall your OS. If you are doing B, then you can just skip to that step.

Even if you do recreate all your partitions, your machine may still not boot after formatting the MBR. If your goal is to replace grub with some other boot loader, you can just follow the steps of installation for the new bootloader. It will take care of the rest.